# Print comma separated items without newline

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I thought I was copying word for word from a [previous question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space), but, I don't get what I wanted.

I was trying to answer a question from an online list of python questions for beginners. I wrote the following in a file called `q.py` and then gave the executed it with `python3 q.py` in my shell.

The file `q.py` looks like:

```
from math import sqrt
C=50
H=30
inp = input('input values:   ')
vals = inp.split(',')
print(vals)
for x in vals:
    D=int(x)
    print(int(sqrt(2*C*D/H)),sep=',',end='')
print()
```

I input `100,150,180` as the question suggested, the required answer is:

```
18,22,24
```

but the answer I get is:

```
182224
```

When I omit the `"end"` argument to `print`, I get `18`, `22`, and `24` separated by newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sep` is used to separate values *if multiple values are actually provided*; you provide *one value* for every loop so the separator isn't used.

Instead of using `sep=','`, use `end=','` to get the desired effect:

```
for x in vals:
    D=int(x)
    print(int(sqrt(2*C*D/H)),end=',')
print()
```

Using similar input, the result printed out is:

```
['100', '150', '180']
18,22,24,
```

If, for example, you provided *multiple* values, say, by unpacking a list comprehension in your `print` call, `sep=','` would work like a charm:

```
print(*[int(sqrt(2*C*int(x)/H)) for x in vals], sep=',')
```

Prints:

```
18,22,24
```